# Error when adding a contribution:

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

When manually adding a contribution - I get the following error:

`Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::calculateMissingAmountParams() (line 383 of /home/sitename/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php).`

Line 383 is:
`$params['net_amount'] = $params['total_amount'] - $params['fee_amount'];`

The contribution is processed without issue - but that error persists. When I add fee amount as 0 - the error does not display. Do we always have to provide a fee amount for manual contribution entries?

[image]

Comment: unless you are already using latest vanilla how about testing on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org to verify what happens there and rule out strangeness related to your set up?

Comment: replicated on Demo - created a new payment method - used that payment method - same error.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a warning (not an error) - so it should let you save the Contribution but nevertheless it should be logged as an issue.

On a production site you will always want display Errors/Warnings -> to none;

In Drupal 7 the setting for that lives:
/admin/config/development/logging

Comment: Hi Karin - we are still testing things - access is still internal to a small group - so we still want errors to appear. The donations do go through - just was unsure about the *warning*.